# socket communication to private network without port forwarding

Tags: sockets, ip, private, router, public

I have an android client which has to communicate through socket to a c# based pc server. The question is, if the pc server is behind a router which somwhow does not seem to support port forwarding through upnp, or even through configuration, it simply cant get connection. 
 These routers are some kind of free wifi zones prepared for free by some kind of companies, so I can't have any access to it's configs. The upnp or configuring my router both works fine, but I dont really know what to do about these routers.

Comment: Why is there a C# server running behind a cafe's public WiFi router? Seems a little suspicious to me.  But whatever. If the cafe's router does not allow port forwarding, the C# server will have to make an outbound connection to a server running in the Android app. If the Android app cannot run its own server that is accessible to the outside world (because of cellular provider restrictions, etc), then you will need a public server on the Internet that both Android and C# apps can connect to, and then have the server act as a relay between them.

Comment: Thanks. Its an app called Smart Print on the appstore which requires this solution. If the pc server is running on some private network which blocks upnp from working it cant get the file to print. My professor who designed this app is getting bug reports and complaints about this and he is forcing me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's common for a home router to only allow established connections by default. Even with a VPN tunnel or CHAP Callback, you would still need configuration on both ends imho.

Comment: Its not about home routers that are making issues. They work just fine. Its about some routers allowed on public which are making issues. I cant reach its config since its provided by others such as companies or cafes.

Comment: And as I said above, it doesnt seem to allow upnp either.